# Orchard CMS: how to get menu navigation in sql?

Tags: sql, menu, navigation, orchardcms

Does anyone know how can I get the navigation menu in sql?

I need this because We have two sites (orchard and mvc site) and We want to use the same header and footer navigation.

We've done a select but the result is getting rows that not appear in the orchard cms site.

```
SELECT M.MenuText, M.MenuPosition, R.DisplayAlias FROM Navigation_MenuPartRecord M
INNER JOIN Navigation_ContentMenuItemPartRecord N ON N.Id = M.Id
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord C ON C.ContentItemRecord_id = N.ContentMenuItemRecord_id
INNER JOIN Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord R ON R.ContentItemRecord_id = N.ContentMenuItemRecord_id
WHERE M.MenuId = @MenuId 
AND R.Id in 
    (
        -- Get the last route part record modified 
        SELECT TOP 1 Id 
        FROM Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord 
        WHERE ContentItemRecord_id = N.ContentMenuItemRecord_id 
        ORDER BY Id DESC
    )
AND C.Published = 1 AND C.Latest = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should never use raw SQL with Orchard. You should set-up a webAPI endpoint in the Orchard application and have the other one query that.

Comment: @Bertrand Exactly what I was about to write. Those queries change dynamically, so you should expose it as an API endpoint. Either expose data or the rendered HTML (if you want Orchard to control the markup for both apps), whichever is better in your case.